# Why does this sometimes crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, uitableview, nsstring

Inside the function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I create an NSString, then give cell.textLabel.text the value of this string. Then I release it. The program will crash on getting one of the fields at the end.

If I don't release the NSString, then the program doesn't crash. But won't this create a memory leak?

Comment: you could try and showthe code where create the NSString etc, my psychic capabilities are a bit limited.

Comment: When looking at these problems, I advise doing a Clean then a "Build and Analyze"... XCode is very good at finding memory leaks or over-relase issues.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It turned out to be something totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you creating the NSString?  If it's anything other than an alloc followed by an init, you don't need to release it!